# Split large text file by date field and save as Month

Tags: text, split

I have large text files ranging from 400mb to 1GB.

Its a tab delimited file with the date being the second field. The records are not sorted by date and can be in any order.

The number of records and period vary from file to file

Each record in the text file has a date field in the format of `14/02/2012` (ie. `dd/mm/yyyy`). I want to split the text files by date and save as Month.txt (e.g `2012Jan.txt`).

The `Jan.txt` file should contain records only for the period `1st Jan 2012` to `31st Jan 2012`.

What would be the best way to do this? Could someone recommend a code/programming tool to achieve this please.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend coding something out and asking questions when you run into problems.Personally,I'd use Java but the language is up to you. :D

Comment: You can use grep if every record is on single line and you're not familiar with programming.

Comment: I'd just open file, read line by line. Read 'Month' from line, check for already opened file for 'Month' - if it's not open then open it for write and store line there. At the end you should close all files. (Hopefully you will not hit system limit of opened files)

Comment: if your on windows you could use .NET (Visual Studio Express), filehandling is quite easy in my eyes. Maybe you could even write a Macro in some office product(excel/word/access).

Comment: Honestly, 1GB is not very big nowadays. You could easily read this into memory, sort it and then loop over it creating files as you go. If you don't have enough RAM for that, open the file, read line by line, and append each line to the appropriate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a Windows .BAT file, with header in each output file:

```
awk "NR==1{header=$0};NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");file=date[3]strftime(\"%%b.txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60);if(!wrote[file]++)print header>file;print>file}" %1
```

(here you pass the name of the input file as an argument to the .BAT call; if it's always the same file, you can change the `%1` to that file name instead)

Comment: Armali my dear friend you are simply amazing. that worked awesome. i am so in love with awk. Could you guide me to some website where i can learn awk with examples. the help file is too complicated. Thanks buddy. Cheers

Comment: Docs with examples:
http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_toc.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_06.html
Some more examples:
http://www.esmerel.com/wagons/rob/scripts.html

Comment: Thanks Armali. You were a great support. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

in a UNIX shell:

```
awk 'NR>1{split($2,date,"/");print>date[3]strftime("%b.txt",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}' large.txt
```

in Windows CMD shell:

```
awk "NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%b.txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" large.txt
```

in a Windows .BAT file:

```
awk "NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%%b.txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" large.txt
```

(assuming your file is named `large.txt`)

Comment: Hi Armali,
Thanks for the Code. However when i run the code i get the following error
"awk: (FILENAME=1.txt FNR=1) fatal error: internal error (SIGSEGV)

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."
Running on Win 7, 32 bit OS, 4 GB RAM
Am i doing something wrong? or are some files missing?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of `awk` are you using (`awk --version`)? I tested with GNU Awk 3.1.6 (from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Comment: I downloaded AWK from the gnu site. I am using version GNU AWK 3.1.6.

Comment: Hi Armali,
i am guessing its somethign to do with maybe admin rights. I have tried running it on a different machine and now it runs. However the output is not as expected. the cod results in an output called 2012b with all the records same as the input file. I want the records to be output to different yyyymmm as per the date. Right now all the different months are coming in the same output file.

Comment: This refers to your comment "I downloaded AWK from the gnu site. I am using version GNU AWK 3.1.6.": Well, or rather, bad, it looks like the GnuWin port of awk has a bug wich surfaces with your input file (`1.txt`, I presume). The right thing to do would be to report it to the Bugs list. Meanwhile, you could try GNU Awk 4.1.0 (e. g. from http://www.klabaster.com/progs/gawk32.zip).

Comment: Could it be that your input file is not quite as you described? Perhaps you could post one line or two from it.

Comment: Or ... that you forgot the `%` in front of the `b.txt`? That would lead to the result you see.

Comment: Hi Armali

Installed Awk 4.1.0,but the output still remains the same. I sort of know the logic but unfortunately dont know the syntax for awk.

Logic is:

Ignore 1st row as its header

From 2nd row onwards capture the 2nd field which has the date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Strip the month & year, save record in file called yyyymm

Create yyyymm file only if not exists,if exists append record to it

Loop thru all the records till end

Result will b some yyyymm files with records only of period yyyymm

Appreciate your help as cannot use excel as the number of rows exceeds Excels limit

Thanks

Comment: The command line above takes care of this logic except for the first line (let's consider that later). Do you paste the command directly in CMD, or how do you execute it? What is the output of the `ver` command?

Comment: Hi Armali, Yes i am copying ur code directly to the cmd line. I also tried putting it in a .bat file. same result. Below are 2 lines excluding the header row from my input file. Date is 2nd field, tab limited file. Have trimmed the number of fields due to space limitations here:

uae 25/02/2012 28 13 44 28 18 39 89 DIRECT DISNEY NATURE
pan 14/01/2012 27 54 46 28 32 8 90 CARAT AEGIS MEDIA

Code i am using in .bat file

gawk "{split($2,date,\"/\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%b.txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" abcd.txt

Comment: It's strange - in the CMD shell, for me it works as it was. But in a .BAT file, we have to double the `%`; I added that case in the answer above, and also the exclusion of the first line (header row).

Comment: Hi Armali,

That worked fantastically well. Thank you so much for putting in the time and effort. Cheers

Comment: is it possible to modify the code to also put the header row of the input file (1st row) into all the output files? Thanks

Comment: It is - see the other answer. And thank you for the question - it made me refresh my knowledge of awk.

Comment: Hi Armali, Could you help me out with some further modification pls. I need the files to continue to be split by Region and Month and now also by the value in field 35. So very unique value in Field 35 i will have separate file now. Possible in awk?  Thanks in advance. Ross

Comment: As this Q&A is already displeasingly long, I suggest to open a new question, with an example how the file names shall look.

Comment: Hi @Armali
made a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906497/awk-split-file-by-value-in-specific-column

Kindly help if possible.
Thanks