# AWK - Split file by value in specific column

Tags: regex, awk, split

I have the following AWK script (provided by Armali on this site) which basically strips a tab delimited file by date(Month/year) and saves it as yyyymmm. I now have another additional condition by which the file should be split. It should be split by Month/year and also by the unique value in Column 3. Save the file as yyyymmm_Col3Uniquevalue.

The current script is

```
awk "NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%%b.txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" input.txt
```

Data Format:

```
Country Date    Type
HongKong    31/01/2012  Television
Japan   14/01/2012  Press
Japan   05/01/2012  Television
Japan   16/02/2013  Press
Japan   15/02/2013  Television
```

Output will be 4 txt files:

```
2012Jan_Press - Containing record 2
2012Jan_Television - Containing record 1,3
2013Feb_Press - Containing record 4
2013Feb_Television - Containing record 5
```

Comment: column 65 ? can you add an example of the text you want to process ?

Comment: Hi Ayoubi, Have modified earlier query and added data format. Pls refer to original post again. Thanks. Data was too big to paste so have changed request from Col 65 to Col 3. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure with just the tiniest bit of thought you could solve this by yourself. It really couldn't be much simpler. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Hi @EdMorton
i tried this but it failed.
awk "NR==1{header=$0};NR>1{split($3,TV,"");file="Hello";if(!wrote[file]++)print header>file;print>file}" EGYOCT05.TXT

Comment: @user2473726 You just need a tiny teak to your original script to append $3 to the file name, but what you posted contains none of your original script. It's hard to see what you were thinking with that.

Comment: Are you using double quotes to delimit the script because you're on Windows? If on UNIX, use single quotes, not double quotes. If on Windows, save the script in a file and execute with `awk -f script`. As written you're making it harder for yourself by needing to escape double quotes, etc. within the script.

Comment: @EdMorton. I am running this as a batch file (.bat) on Windows. (Command line)

Comment: OK, then put the awk script in a file and invoke it as `awk -f file` to avoid Windows horrific quoting rules - that's what causing all of the pointless escaping in the script you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TAB separated fields...:

```
awk -F\t "NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%%b_\"$3\".txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" input.txt
```

`$3` had to be excluded from the quoted format string.

If the date field `$2` contains after a space also the time, split by space as well as by "/" to keep getting the year in `date[3]`:

```
awk -F\t "NR>1{split($2,date,\"[/ ]\");print>date[3]strftime(\"%%b_\"$3\".txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" input.txt
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `> a b` will be treated as `> (a b)` rather than `(> a) b`. You need to explicitly parenthesize.

Comment: @Armali
For some strange the script gets confused between space and tab. In my above data if the last column is say Tele Vision (space not tab, between tele and vision) then it save the file ending as Tele. It ignores data after space. If the first column is say Hong Kong (space between Hong and Kong) then it crashes. Apparently it is taking space as a field delimiter rather than tab. How can i fix this?. Ruuning as a batch file in Windows. Thanks

Comment: What you observed is not strange; by default, fields are separated by whitespace. To make only TAB the field delimiter, you can use the option `-F\t`; I'll edit the command above accordingly.

Comment: @Armali I am getting an error messg when i put the -f\t in a batch file. Error is "awk: fatal: can't open source file `\t' for reading (No such file or directory)"  i also tried -f"\t" and -f"\\t". both didn't work. am i doing something wrong? Thks

Comment: Yes, what you did wrong was disregarding the upper case of `F`.

Comment: @Armali i changed it to small case becoz even the upper case resulted in an error. I have been breaking my head since yest,I caught the error being the split($2,date) part. The field was dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss the space between the date and time was causing the error as filename cudnt have a colon in it. I am happy that i have fixed it myself.am sure you will have a more elegant solution. happy that i did something in awk myself :) the modified script is
'code' awk -F\t "NR>1{split($2,date,\"/\");print>substr(date[3],1,4) strftime(\"%%b_\"$35\".txt\",(date[2]-1)*31*24*60*60)}" input.txt 'code'

Comment: Well done! I'll add a perhaps slightly more elegant solution to the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Play with this for a bit to make sure you understand it:

```
$ cat file
Country Date    Type
HongKong    31/01/2012  Television
Japan   14/01/2012  Press
Japan   05/01/2012  Television
Japan   16/02/2013  Press
Japan   15/02/2013  Television

$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
   split($2,a,"/")
   secs = mktime(a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" 0 0 0")
   mth  = strftime("%b", secs)
   file = a[3] mth "_" $3
   print file
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2012Jan_Television
2012Jan_Press
2012Jan_Television
2013Feb_Press
2013Feb_Television
```

Look up `mktime()` and `strftime()` in the GNU awk manual.

Just change `print file` to `print > file` when you're done testing.